# char** to cope with string?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I got quite confused when I came across char**, is it really necessary to cope with string?
For example:

```
double strtod(const char *nptr,char **endptr);
```

If `endptr` is not NULL, a pointer to the character that stopped the scan is stored at the location pointed to by `endptr`. ---MSDN
This is quite complicated, why not just copy pointer to the character to `endptr`? All computations after the call can be achieved by passing the pointer's value to `endptr` as I think.
*Is `char**` really needed?*

Comment: `char **` is needed because you pass in a `char *` you need changed.

Comment: It's a small smattering of type safety that has accidentally crept into C :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine there's a type called `my_type`, and you have a function called `foo()` that needs a pointer to a `my_type` so that it can modify it:

```
void foo(my_type *t);
```

Now, lets look at how `my_type` is actually defined:

```
typedef char* my_type;
```

So it doesn't matter if the type is already a pointer. If you want to pass a pointer to a variable of that type, you need its address. So the decomposition of:

```
my_type *t
```

would be:

```
char **t
```

Whenever you want a pointer to a variable of type `char *`, you need a `char **`.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments in C are passed by value. If you want the caller of a function to see a change made to an argument passed to a function you need to pass the address of the argument to the function. This is why the `char**` is being passed. The caller has a variable of type `char*` and passes its address. If it is changed in the function the caller can see that change.

For example:

```
void set_int(int i) { i = 4; }

/* Caller */
int x = 7;
set_int(x);
/* 'x' is still 7 */

void really_set_int(int* i) { *i = 4; }

/* Caller */
int x = 7;
really_set_int(&x);
/* 'x' is now 4 */
```

The same behaviour for a variable of type `char*`. If a function needs to change what the `char*` is *pointing to* (not its content) it needs the address of the `char*`, which is of type `char**`.

Comment: So if I pass "char* endptr" and use "endptr = 0x30160700"(for example), the actual value of "endptr" outside the function will stay the same?

Comment: @Rubby, no. After the call `endptr` will point to a different location.

Comment: @Rubby, if the parameter was `char* endptr` then any change made to the pointer would not be visible to the caller.