# Realloc an int array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to create an array to hold an int, then when another int is to be added increase it in size to hold another int.. and so on..

I know it's not an efficient use of realloc, but it's proof on concept more than anything else. Just to get it working would allow me to optimise it and be able to apply it to something useful. A working example. The problem comes when i call the print function and it just segfaults. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char String[100];

void begin(int *);
void add(int *, int);
void print(int *);

int tempcount=0;

int main(void)
{
    int *n=NULL;
    String menu;

    begin(n);

    while(true)
    {
        scanf("%9s", menu);

        if(!strcmp("a", menu)) //add
        {
            int i=0;
            scanf("%d", &i);
            add(n, i);
        }
        else if(!strcmp("p", menu)) //print
        {
            print(n);
        }
        else if(!strcmp("q", menu)) //quit
        {
            free(n);
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void begin(int *n)
{
    n=malloc(sizeof(int));

    if(n==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in malloc!");
        return;
    }

    n[0]=0;

    printf("Added %d \n", n[0]);
}

void add(int *n, int numToAdd)
{
    static int sizeCount=0;
    sizeCount++;
    tempcount=sizeCount;

    int *temp;

    temp=realloc(n, (sizeCount+1) * sizeof(int));

    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in realloc!");
        return;
    }

    n=temp;

    n[sizeCount]=numToAdd;

    printf("Added %d \n", n[sizeCount]);

}

void print(int *n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<tempcount; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", n[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `realloc` returns a pointer?

Comment: because it does?

Comment: This is related and thus of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13098037/856199

Comment: @n.m. because its signature is `void *(*)(void *, size_t);` perhaps?

Comment: @H2CO3: very smart. why this signature and not any other?

Comment: @n.m. I don't get this. This signature is the signature of `realloc()`, because that's how it's defined in the standard library.

Comment: @hexist: `realloc` is an artefact engineered for a particular purpose, not a random natural phenomenon. Its signature is a direct consequence of its purpose.

Comment: @n.m.: `realloc` returns a pointer because it can't guarantee the "resized" block of memory will be in the same spot as the old.  If it has to move the block, it needs some way to tell you where the new block is.

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, but why is it defined this way?

Comment: @n.m. nevermind :) cHao just answered that.

Comment: @n.m. not sure what you're trying to say. `realloc` is well defined to take a pointer to `NULL` or an existing `malloc`'ed block, a new size, and return a pointer to either the same pointer if it could do the resize in place, or the new pointer you should use if it had to move your data. It's pretty well defined.. ya know, by international standards and such (ISO 9899)

Comment: @cHao: I appreciate your and everybody else's knowledge but the question was intended for the original poster. It was an attempt to guide him to an answer he could figure out mostly himself, instead of providing a ready-made one. It's too late anyway.

Comment: @n.m.: You might want to be more up-front about that kind of thing in the future.  :)  Now that i look at your questions with that info, it's semi obvious where you were going with it...but before you clarified the intent, it looked like you were just totally mystified by `realloc`.

Comment: @cHao: ok, in the future I will state in big bold letters that the question is a pedagogical device ;)

Comment: @n.m. Next time ask "What do you think is the reason..." to prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to your pointers in add/begin so they can modify your pointer in main

```
begin(&n);
...
add(&n, i);
```

and your definition

```
void begin(int **n)
{
    *n=malloc(sizeof(int));

    if(*n==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in malloc!");
        return;
    }

    (*n)[0]=0;

    printf("Added %d \n", (*n)[0]);
}
```

and

```
void add(int **n, int numToAdd)
{
    static int sizeCount=0;
    sizeCount++;
    tempcount=sizeCount;

    int *temp;

    temp=realloc(*n, (sizeCount+1) * sizeof(int));

    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in realloc!");
        return;
    }

    *n=temp;

    (*n)[sizeCount]=numToAdd;

    printf("Added %d \n", (*n)[sizeCount]);

}
```

Right now what you're doing is modifying local copies of your pointer in begin/add, so when you change it in those functions it's not modifying your pointer `n` in main

Also, fun fact, if you pass `NULL` as the first parameter to `realloc` it acts like a `malloc`, so if you initialize `n` to `NULL`, you can simply call `add` without first doing a `begin`.

Comment: The same, passing the array _by reference_, has to be done for the `add` function as well.

Comment: @hexist: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer, it really helped and i have the program working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your function add - are you sure you update the pointer value?
Try with ** as a parameter - I think it will help.